# Function to calculate shift between to time series based on data points

Tags: r, timeshift

I am trying to find a function that matches two time series such that the datetime corresponds to reality.

So I need a function that minimizes the distance between the two curves shown above and outputs a new dataframe that has TAIR time-shifted towards the values of tre200h0.

From my bare eyes, it looks like this shift is about 22h.

[ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eUqv.png)

Best,

Fabio

I don't know a function that does this job for me.

Comment: Two R base functions to analyze time series lags are `acf` and `pacf`. i.e. given you have x and y  you can use `acf(y-x)` and seek the zeroes in the plot (if your series have adequate seasonal behaviour), or, if you prefer, `acf(y-x, plot=F)` and get the data. Try `which.min( acf(x-y)$acf^2 )`. Of course, it is a simplification of otherwise complex matter.

Comment: Thanks this should solve it! The shift was exactley 22 hours, but this can be useful for future reference. 

F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by Ric Villalba in the comments to OG Question.

Two R base functions to analyze time series lags are `acf` and `pacf`. i.e. given you have x and y you can use `acf(y-x)` and seek the zeroes in the plot (if your series have adequate seasonal behaviour), or, if you prefer, `acf(y-x, plot=F)` and get the data. Try `which.min( acf(x-y)$acf^2 )`.

Of course, it is a simplification of otherwise complex matter